# How to avoid violating the DRY principle when you have to have both async and sync versions of code?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm working on a project that needs to support both async and sync version of a same logic/method. So for example I need to have:

```
public class Foo
{
   public bool IsIt()
   {
      using (var conn = new SqlConnection(DB.ConnString))
      {
         return conn.Query<bool>("SELECT IsIt FROM SomeTable");
      }
   }

   public async Task<bool> IsItAsync()
   {
      using (var conn = new SqlConnection(DB.ConnString))
      {
         return await conn.QueryAsync<bool>("SELECT IsIt FROM SomeTable");
      }
   }
}
```

The async and sync logic for these methods are identical in every respect except that one is async and another one is not. Is there a legitimate way to avoid violating the DRY principle in this kind of a scenario? I saw that people say you could use GetAwaiter().GetResult() on an async method and invoke it from your sync method? Is that thread safe in all scenarios? Is there another, better way to do this or am I forced to duplicate the logic?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what you are doing here? Specifically, how are you achieving asynchrony in your asynchronous method? Is the high-latency work CPU bound or IO bound?

Comment: "one is async and another one is not" is the difference in actual method's code or just interface? (Clearly for just interface you can `return Task.FromResult(IsIt());`)

Comment: Also, presumably the synchronous and asynchronous versions are both high-latency. Under what circumstances will the caller use the synchronous version, and how is that caller going to mitigate the fact that the callee could take billions of nanoseconds? Does the caller of the synchronous version not care that they are hanging the UI? Is there no UI?  Tell us more about the scenario.

Comment: @EricLippert I added a specific dummy example just to give you a sense how 2 codes bases are identical other than the fact that one is async. You can easily imagine a scenario where this method is much more complex and lines and lines of code have to be duplicated.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The difference is indeed in code, I added some dummy code to demo it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample code; that clarifies things. In this case the high-latency operation is likely bound on IO, not processor, so it does not make sense to do the work in a worker thread; that is inefficient. If you were waiting for a letter, you would not hire a worker to sleep beside the mailbox and wake up when the letter arrives; that is enormously expensive. You'd periodically check the mailbox and get work done while you were asynchronously waiting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You asked several questions in your question. I will break them down slightly differently than you did. But first let me directly answer the question.

We all want a camera that is lightweight, high quality, and cheap, but like the saying goes, you can only get at most two out of those three.  You are in the same situation here. You want a solution that is efficient, safe, and shares code between the synchronous and asynchronous paths. You're only going to get two of those.

Let me break down why that is.  We'll start with this question:

---

> I saw that people say you could use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on an async method and invoke it from your sync method? Is that thread safe in all scenarios?

The point of this question is "can I share the synchronous and asynchronous paths by making the synchronous path simply do a synchronous wait on the asynchronous version?"

Let me be super clear on this point because it is important:

**YOU SHOULD IMMEDIATELY STOP TAKING ANY ADVICE FROM THOSE PEOPLE**.

That is extremely bad advice. It is very dangerous to synchronously fetch a result from an asynchronous task *unless you have evidence that the task has completed normally or abnormally*.

The reason this is extremely bad advice is, well, consider this scenario.  You want to mow the lawn, but your lawn mower blade is broken. You decide to follow this workflow:

- Order a new blade from a web site.  This is a high-latency, asynchronous operation.
- Synchronously wait -- that is, **sleep until you have the blade in hand**.
- Periodically check the mailbox to see if the blade has arrived.
- Remove the blade from the box. Now you have it in hand.
- Install the blade in the mower.
- Mow the lawn.

What happens?  You sleep forever because the operation of *checking the mail* is now *gated on something that happens after the mail arrives*.

It is *extremely easy* to get into this situation when you synchronously wait on an arbitrary task. **That task might have work scheduled in the future of the thread that is now waiting**, and now that future will never arrive because you are waiting for it.

If you do an *asynchronous wait* then everything is fine!  You periodically check the mail, and while you are waiting, you make a sandwich or do your taxes or whatever; you keep getting work done while you are waiting.

Never synchronously wait. If the task is done, it is *unnecessary*. If the task is not done but scheduled to run off the current thread, it is *inefficient* because the current thread could be servicing other work instead of waiting. If the task is not done and schedule run on the current thread, it is *hanging* to synchronously wait.  There is no good reason to synchronously wait, again, *unless you already know that the task is complete*.

For further reading on this topic, see

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Stephen explains the real-world scenario much better than I can.

---

Now let's consider the "other direction".  Can we share code by making the asynchronous version simply do the synchronous version on a worker thread?

That is *possibly* and indeed *probably* a bad idea, for the following reasons.

- It is inefficient if the synchronous operation is high-latency IO work. This essentially hires a worker and makes that worker *sleep* until a task is done. Threads are *insanely expensive*. They consume a million bytes of address space minimum by default, they take time, they take operating system resources; you do not want to burn a thread doing useless work.
- The synchronous operation might not be written to be thread safe.
- This *is* a more reasonable technique if the high-latency work is processor bound, but if it is then you probably do not want to simply hand it off to a worker thread. You likely want to use the task parallel library to parallelize it to as many CPUs as possible, you likely want cancellation logic, and you can't simply make the synchronous version do all that, because *then it would be the asynchronous version already*.

Further reading; again, Stephen explains it very clearly:

Why not to use Task.Run:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html

More "do and don't" scenarios for Task.Run:

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

---

What does that then leave us with?  Both techniques for sharing code lead to either deadlocks or large inefficiencies. The conclusion that we reach is that you must make a choice. Do you want a program that is efficient and correct and delights the caller, or do you want to save a few keystrokes entailed by duplicating a small amount of code between the synchronous and asynchronous paths?  You don't get both, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you explain why returning `Task.Run(() => SynchronousMethod())` in the async version isn't what the OP want?

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy: The original poster has answered the question of what the work is: it is IO bound. It is wasteful to run IO bound tasks on a worker thread!

Comment: Alright I understand. I think you are right, and also @StriplingWarrior answer explains it even more.

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy: I added some links to Stephen Cleary articles that answer your question in more detail.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for your elaborate answer. I do have a question for you regarding this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context. Here it says that this solution is thread safe but you sort of shoot it down in Keith's answer bellow. Can you explain why is this workaround bad? Is it just a performance issue?

Comment: @Marko almost any workaround that blocks the thread will eventually (under high load) consume all threadpool threads (that usually used to complete async operations). As result all threads will be waiting and none will be available to let operations to run "async operation completed" part of the code. Most workarounds are fine in low load scenarios (as there are plenty of threads even 2-3 are blocked as part of each single operation)… And if you can guarantee that completion of async operation runs on new OS thread (not thread pool) it may even work for all cases (you pay high price so)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah I suspected as much but it is surprising to me that on the official Microsoft blog it says to use this as a thread safe workaround. Why would you suggest such a solution to public if you know it's going to cause them headaches in the future? No wonder there is so much confusion around this topic.

Comment: Sometimes there is really no other way than "simply do the synchronous version on a worker thread". For example, that's how `Dns.GetHostEntryAsync` is implemented in .NET, and `FileStream.ReadAsync` for certain types of files. The OS simply provides no async interface, so the runtime has to fake it (and it's not language specific—say, Erlang runtime runs entire tree of worker *processes*, with multiple threads inside each, to provide non-blocking disk I/O and name resolution).

Comment: @GuillaumeSasdy Depends on what the underlying logic is. Many methods are async because the third-party code they call is async, so you have to start with the async code and make it synchronous again.

Answer (score 6):

It's difficult to give a one-size-fits-all answer to this one. Unfortunately there's no simple, perfect way to get reuse between asynchronous and synchronous code. But here are a few principles to consider:

1. Asynchronous and Synchronous code is often fundamentally different. Asynchronous code should usually include a cancellation token, for example. And often it ends up calling different methods (as your example calls `Query()` in one and `QueryAsync()` in the other), or setting up connections with different settings. So even when it's structurally similar, there are often enough differences in behavior to merit them being treated as separate code with different requirements. Note the differences between [Async](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/File.cs,1c7421e464f67b7e) and [Sync](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/File.cs,675b2259e8706c26) implementations of methods in the File class, for example: no effort is made to make them use the same code
2. If you're providing an Asynchronous method signature for the sake of implementing an interface, but you happen to have a synchronous implementation (i.e. there's nothing inherently async about what your method does), you can simply return `Task.FromResult(...)`.
3. Any synchronous pieces of logic which *are* the same between the two methods can be extracted to a separate helper method and leveraged in both methods.

Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

Easy; have the synchronous one call the async one. There's even a handy method on `Task<T>` to do just that:

```
public class Foo
{
   public bool IsIt()
   {
      var task = IsItAsync(); //no await here; we want the Task

      //Some tasks end up scheduled to run before you get them;
      //don't try to run them a second time
      if((int)task.Status > (int)TaskStatus.Created)
          //this call will block the current thread,
          //and unlike Run()/Wait() will prefer the current 
          //thread's TaskScheduler instead of a new thread.
          task.RunSynchronously(); 

      //if IsItAsync() can throw exceptions,
      //you still need a Wait() call to bring those back from the Task
      try{ 
          task.Wait();
          return task.Result;
      }
      catch(Exception ex) 
      { 
          //Handle IsItAsync() exceptions here;
          //remember to return something if you don't rethrow              
      }
   }

   public async Task<bool> IsItAsync()
   {
      // Some async logic
   }
}
```

Comment: See my answer for why this is a worst practice that you must never do.

Comment: Your answer deals with GetAwaiter().GetResult(). I avoided that. The reality is that sometimes you have to make a method run synchronously in order to use it in a call stack that cannot be made async. If sync waits should never be done, then as a (former) member of the C# team, please tell me why you put not one but two ways to synchronously wait on an asynchronous task into the TPL.

Comment: The person to ask that question would be Stephen Toub, not me. I only worked on the language side of things.